# How do I know whether to remove the column, or rows when dealing with null data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, machine-learning

Here is the head of my Dataframe. I am trying to remove the NaN values in the column "Type 2", but I am not sure how to decide whether to remove the entire column containing the NaN values, or remove the rows containing the NaN values. How should I decide which method to use to remove the NaN values? Is there a certain threshold to determine whether to remove the rows or the entire column, for datasets in general? My end goal is to run a machine learning algorithm on this dataset to predict whether or not a Pokemon is Legendary. Thank you

```
#   Name    Type 1  Type 2  Total   HP  Attack  Defense Sp. Atk Sp. Def Speed   Generation  Legendary
2   3   Venusaur    Grass   Poison  525 80  82  83  100 100 80  1   False
3   3   VenusaurMega Venusaur   Grass   Poison  625 80  100 123 122 120 80  1   False
5   5   Charmeleon  Fire    NaN 405 58  64  58  80  65  80  1   False
9   7   Squirtle    Water   NaN 314 44  48  65  50  64  43  1   False
10  8   Wartortle   Water   NaN 405 59  63  80  65  80  58  1   False
15  12  Butterfree  Bug Flying  395 60  45  50  90  80  70  1   False
```

Comment: This is not a pandas DataFrame....

Comment: Depends, the question you need to ask yourself is what you want to do.

Comment: You can do either and both answer are justified along with many other ways to deal with null data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes we can decide a threshold for this.
if you have NAN values in all columns is best use:

```
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
```

this we drop all hows that contain NAN´s, if you use axis=1 will delete all columns that have NAN values.

One thing that you need think is how much percent of the values in a column is NAN, if more that 70% of NAN values is in only one column and i have no other way to complete this I delete this column.
if the NAN values is distributed in the columns is better delete rows.

i hope it helped you.

Comment: What if there are multiple columns with null data? Removing the rows for each null value will greatly size down your dataset resulting in a skewed model. Is there a threshold that can adjust for this or no?

Comment: yes. you can use a algorithm to predict this values. but if a column has low values this can be a problem.

Comment: About the threshold this is complicated. you need make testes to know how is the best way to use you data. Example: you can delete a column and test the algorithm with the appropriated metrics. you can predict the nan values with a KNN for example and test. don´t exist a general threshold for this.

Comment: Say I am just formatting this for multiple linear regression. How should I find a threshold

Comment: first: look in each column and count how much percents of the data are NAN if more that 40%.(delete this column for the first test.)

Comment: second: in columns that has less that 40% NAN values you can predict this misseds values. the options are: mean of the column.(for continuos values only.), median of the column.(for discrete values.), or you can use a Model like KNN, Decision Tree to predict this values.

Answer (score 1):

> I would restrain from deleting whole rows in this scenario.

When deleting rows you would probably never have a pokemon in your dataset which has NaN as second type.

```
5   5   Charmeleon  Fire    NaN 405 58  64  58  80  65  80  1   False
```

In a next step it is easy to think of a legendary Pokemon which does not have a second type. You would never be able to predict such a Pokemon correctly.

You could still delete the column, but you would loose information.
Other than deleting I'd rather introduce an `undefined_type` tag for those `NaN` values and go from there.

```
5   5   Charmeleon  Fire    undefined_type 405 58  64  58  80  65  80  1   False
```

Above those things you should do some feature analysis to find out which features actually do contribute to the information gain (e.g. random forest with elbow method). If the introduction of the `undefined_type` tag reduces the information gain of that feature, you'll know after this analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think your best bet would be to make the types categorical and have the NaN's in the type column be a category as well. This would make your machine learning model more robust.